# how could i sseparate only two key and value from an array..?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

```
[0: {source: "google", flightnumber: "103", Jul 1: 2397, Jul 2: 2397, Jul 3: 2397},
1: {source: "expedia", flightnumber: "169", Jul 1: 2397, Jul 2: 2397, Jul 3: 2397}]
```

i need to show only array with source and selected date (example :Jul 3)

example

```
[0: {source: "google",  Jul 3: 2397},
1: {source: "expedia", Jul 3: 2397}]
```

Comment: thats not valid obj lieteral.  maybe need quote around "Jul 1" etc.

Comment: ``data.map(k=>({source:k.source, 'Jul 3':k[`Jul 3`]}))``

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are trying to use it but you can use a map to map through the array and return a new modified array like this

```
tet modifiedArray = originalArray.map(fireFighter => {

        return {source: fireFighter.source,  "Jul 3": fireFighter["Jul 3"]}

    }
)
```

That is assuming that you know the key name `"Jul 3"` remains the same all the time.